# Comparando duas arrays em JS

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um código para uma extensão do Chrome em que desejo pegar todo o texto presente na página de qualquer site, colocar em um array e comparar com uma array pré-existente de palavras específicas. Consigo pegar as palavras na página e colocar em um array para a comparação, mas na hora de apresentar a interseção entre as duas, ela retorna uma array vazia. E são palavras presentes na página que estou testando.

Alguém sabe qual pode ser o problema? Segue o código:

```
function check() {

  let badWords = ['Spot', 'Cakes', 'Work'];
  console.log(badWords);

  let pageWords = [];
  pageWords.push(document.documentElement.textContent.split(' ') || document.documentElement.innerText.split(' '));
  console.log(pageWords);

  let gotYou = badWords.filter(a => pageWords.includes(a));
  console.log(gotYou);

}

check();`
```

Inclusive testo se a palavra existe com um indexOf, e retorna true.

```
console.log(pageWords.indexOf('Work↵') > -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os métodos:

```
    document.documentElement.textContent.split(' ') e

    document.documentElement.innerText.split(' ')
```

já retornam um array, então você deve aplicar o

> includes

no index 0 do array pageWords
ficando assim:

```
function check() {

  let badWords = ['Spot', 'Cakes', 'Work'];
  console.log(badWords);

  let pageWords = [];
  pageWords.push(document.documentElement.textContent.split(' ') || document.documentElement.innerText.split(' '));
  console.log(pageWords);

  let gotYou = badWords.filter(a => pageWords[0].includes(a));
  console.log(gotYou);

}
```